# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use

```
let op = data.map(({usp-custom-90})=> usp-custom-90 )
```

but that gives

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

I tried to replace dash with – but then I get errors in regards of &

How do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot use `-` as part of an identifier in JavaScript.

Comment: so how could I fix that? I cannot change the name of the custom field usp-custom-90

Comment: You have posted nothing at all about what the contents of `data` actually looks like, nor have you described what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Pointy it's some data I am receiving from a json, but the issue isn't within the json, I am having the error as soon as I run the code, and that is because of the dash, here it is a jsfiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/7g6tcdor/8/

Comment: The code should be posted *here*. A fiddle is fine, but Stackoverflow also has facilities to set up a demonstration of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifiers cannot contain hyphens, so you must rename the property to a valid identifier name:

```
let op = data.map( ({ ['usp-custom-90']: uspCustom90 }) => uspCustom90 )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use computed property name

```
let prop = `usp-custom-90`
let op = data.map(({[prop]:p})=> p)
```